# Classifier choice for 荚谜

Tags: grammar, measure-word

**Cross-post notice**

I usually wait for a week before cross-posting, but it's been 6 days, so I decided not to wait till tomorrow. Again, asked on Quora, no response, marked as needing editing.

**Question**

> What classifier is best suited for the word 莢蒾, "guelder rose"? In particular, is there a better choice than the general-purpose 个?

NOTE: I know "guelder rose" is actually 欧洲荚谜, but I used this in a song translation where I do not have enough syllables for that 4-syllable name, so I dropped Ōuzhōu, hoping the difference won't be excessive.

**NOTE 2**

While "guelder rose" suggests a flower and hence 朵, [this is 欧洲荚谜](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viburnum_opulus) (aka viburnum opulus) and [this is just 荚谜](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viburnum_dilatatum) (aka viburnum dilatatum). Both of these are more like bushes than flowers, so I feel 朵 would not be correct. One might argue that 一朵荚谜 would be a flower of viburnum dilatatum, but in the song I need this for I believe the whole plant is what is being referred to, not just the flower, so 朵 doesn't feel right to me.

Comment: Rose? 朵? No? What else?

Comment: @user3306356 Given that we are talking about [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viburnum_opulus), which is rather a bush or plant than a flower, I wonder why it's "guelder rose" in English, and feel 朵 may not be the right answer, since it is for flowers.

Comment: One may use 朵 to refer to the plant's flowers, but in the song I believe the whole plant is being referred to.

Comment: @user3306356 added that as a NOTE to the question.

Comment: Then perhaps 株 or 簇

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would suggest 叢 (u+53e2):

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?ccd=vZFQLg&o=e0&sec=sec1&op=v&view=0-2

eg 一叢莢蒾